# What's this gap between the right end of the mode-line and the fringe when changing font's size?

Tags: fonts, mode-line

I'm toying around with font sizes in Emacs and I noticed that changing the font size to something huge, like, 160, creates a gap between the right end of the mode-line and the fringe:

[image: screenshot of the issue]

This is the code I ran on my scratch buffer:

```
(let ((faces '(mode-line
               mode-line-buffer-id
               mode-line-emphasis
               mode-line-highlight
               mode-line-inactive)))
  (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height (* 16 10))
  (mapc (lambda (face) (set-face-attribute face nil :height (* 9 10))) faces))
```

Yes, I'm trying to keep the mode-line font size I currently use (900)

Comment: The mode-line gets filled from left to right.  So anything on the right is there because of a filler -- e.g., `read-only column 22 line 13 filler filler filler filler stuff-on-right`.  If the filler is based on a particular font that becomes smaller, then there will be extra space on the right. You'll need to dig into the contents of the `mode-line-format` and see what else is there and modify it accordingly so that things are pushed to the right with additional filler.  Or, like most of us, use the mode-line from left to right without any filler -- this is the default behavior.

Comment: @lawlist: Please consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode-line gets filled from left to right.  Anything in the mode-line that is clearly skewed to the right is most likely occurring because a filler has been used -- e.g., `read-only column 22 line 13 filler filler filler filler stuff-on-right`.

If the filler is based on a particular font that becomes smaller, or if certain textual components of the mode-line become smaller due to a font change or font size reduction, then there may appear to be extra space on the right.  The original poster should research the contents of the `mode-line-format` to see what else is present, and modify those aspects accordingly so that certain aspects appear to be better right-aligned (using additional filler).

Or, like many users, the original poster could try out the default behavior of the mode-line without using any filler.